# Why is my Subscribe Function not Running?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, iot, publish-subscribe

I have followed the example on the AWS website to a tee
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/pubsub

and no matter what happens every time I run 
await PubSub.publish
I get no response from AWS. Any Help would be appreciated. 
I am getting time outs for the code.

Triend diffrent ways of interacting with AWS over MQTT react-native. Searched everywhere. No examples of this being used.

```js
import Amplify, { PubSub, Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

import { AWSIoTProvider } from '@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib/Providers';

import aws_exports from './src/aws-exports';

// aythentication import
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);


Amplify.addPluggable(new AWSIoTProvider({
     aws_pubsub_region: 'us-east-1',
     aws_pubsub_endpoint:  'wss://azk3aah4ivg82-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mqtt',
}));

PubSub.subscribe(['$aws/things/B_Bone_1/shadow/get/accepted', '$aws/things/B_Bone_1/shadow/get/rejected']).subscribe({
    next: data => console.log('Message received get accepted', data),
    error: error => console.error(error),
    close: () => console.log('Done'),
});


//
export default class Main extends React.Component {
//...... sign in stuff This just makes a cognito accound and lets me log in. Its working
}


class App extends Component {
//constuct props 
///...
update = async () => {

    await PubSub.publish('$aws/things/B_Bone_1/shadow/update', {msg: '{"state":{"reported":{"temp": -1}}}' });

    Alert.alert('Update all local values from Device Shadow');
  }


render() {
    return (
    //A page with a button that runs update function
    );
    }}
    
//Stylesheet stuff
```

When calling update the program should run the subscribe function. But i get a timeout error as nothing is returned.
Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loggt on VERBOSE?

`Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'VERBOSE';`

> Maybe you need a provider ?

`core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Could not find provider named [object Object]`

Like me, not solved yet :-(